# Is there a hook or sth after file is uploaded via file field?

Tags: 7, entities, hooks, files

I have drupal 7 installation with file field + video field(and media module). I can change where to upload files in video field setting(default: videos/original).
I'm trying to do stuff to videos after file is uploaded and node is saved.
Is there a hook I can use to achieve this?

What I want Exactly: Make a copy of the videos to 2 different servers via ftp and some transcode codes. First file needs to be uploaded to drupal folder and after that I need my code to run. sometimes videos need to be converted using ffmpeg(move to videos/converted) and then I run my code.

I've found these hooks but none of theme get called after uploading files or even after saving the node:

hook_file_copy($file, $source)

hook_file_move($file, $source)

how about this one?

hook_field_insert or hook_node_insert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`hook_node_insert()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7) and/or [`hook_node_update()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_update/7) would probably be the right place to do this. Your code might look something like this:

```
function MYMODULE_node_insert($node) {
  // See if a file has been added
  if ($file_items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_file')) {
    // Get the first file item
    $file_item = array_shift($file_items);

    // Load the file object from the cache/database
    $file = file_load($file_item['fid']);

    // The path to the file is in $file->uri
    do_something_with($file->uri);
  }
}
```